# spring controller referring to service using configuration file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc project. I have a controller defined as follows:

```
public class HelloController {

    private HelloService helloService;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public void sayHello() {
        helloService.sayHello();
    }
}
```

My service is as follows:

```
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {

public void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello Spring !");
}
}
```

The interface is as follows:

```
public interface HelloService {

void sayHello();
}
```

and my configuration file is as follows:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pack"/>

<bean id="HelloController" class="com.pack.controllers.HelloController">
    <property name="helloService" ref="HelloService"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="HelloService" class="com.pack.services.HelloServiceImpl"/>
```

I can use annotations on the `controller` and the `service` and `autowire` the service using annotation `@autowired` which works fine. 
I was trying to achieve the same using configuration file. Is there a way to do it ?

I am getting the following exception while running it:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'HelloController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'helloService' of bean class [adams.invincible.controllers.HelloController]: Bean property 'helloService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1423)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'helloService' of bean class [adams.invincible.controllers.HelloController]: Bean property 'helloService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1042)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
    org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Putting `@Autowired` on a field is a bad practice. Now you have experienced why it's bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by providing setter method for injecting helloService as shown below
 //setter injection

```
  public void setHelloService(HelloService helloService) {
    this.helloService = helloService;
  }
```

Or You can achieve it by providing constructor for injecting helloService using constructor injection as shown below
//Constructor injection

```
 public HelloController (HelloService helloService) {
   this.helloService = helloService;
}
```

// changes in configuration file

```
<bean id="HelloController" class="com.pack.controllers.HelloController">
    <constructor-arg ref="HelloService"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the setter and getter for helloservice in HelloController class will take care of it. There should **NOT** be a need to add @autowired annotation after doing that

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you need generate the get and set for the bean helloService.

*Bean property 'helloService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter*

But if you trying inject the bean, even making the configuration manually , you need to put the annotation @Autowire

```
@Autowire
private HelloService helloService;
```

Comment: Adding `@Autowired` is pointless if you have an XML configuration.